# Azure API Redirect endpoint to another search service

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have an Azure API set up that listens on /* and sends the query through to a search service backend on https://name.search.windows.net/indexes/appnames/docs/.

I want to add a second endpoint that listens on /filters and have that point to another search https://name.search.windows.net/indexes/appfilters/docs/.

I have used **set-backend-service base-url** to correctly point to the second search service backend but the url that gets used still includes the **/filters**, i.e. https://name.search.windows.net/indexes/appfilters/docs/filters rather than https://name.search.windows.net/indexes/appfilters/docs/.

How can I remove the filters/ part of the uri that I am using to switch the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just have to use the [`rewrite-uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#RewriteURL) policy to remove it by adding this line in the inbound section

```xml
<rewrite-uri template="/" />
```

Comment: I would have sworn I tried this several times but you are absolutely right this is all that is required.